# Is ResourceBundle.getBundle() unable to take a file named local.properties?

Tags: java, jsp, local, resourcebundle

I have a local.properties file that lives outside the classpath I am using a modification of the ResourceBundle.getBundle call and what I noticed when debugging is it will not allow me to have the file named local.properties ( other attempts at log.properties & local2.properties all work fine )

```
    final File file = new File("C:\\tmp"); // (PATH);

    final URL[] urls = { file.toURI().toURL() };
    final ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    final ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("local", Locale.getDefault(), loader);

    final Enumeration<String> keys = rb.getKeys();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
        final String key = keys.nextElement();
        final String value = rb.getString(key);
        System.out.println("key is " + key + " + the value is " + value);
```

I have no idea what else I could do to get this to work. Oddly the final solution to this is to have the data sent to a JSP, when I put the code in directly into a jsp page it works. Open to reasons why this doesn't work in a *.java form or any suggestions to display a local.properties file into a jsp.

Comment: Have you tried placing the resource file in your classpath, so that you don't have to pass a `URLClassLoader` to `getBundle`?

Comment: Short answer : due to other restrictions cannot do this.
Long Answer : the local.properties file is used for the SSO configuration durning another setup that is scripted. So it lives in another land, outside of classpath.

Do you think the URL loader is somehow the problem ?